# How to backup a mongodb collection using express.js and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to take a backup of my `userdatas` collection every month.

Backup means:

I need to take `userdatas` data and store it in some `backupuserdatas` collection. Every 1 month a batch program should run automatically and should store that month of data(documents) in the `backupuserdatas` collection.

I have used node-cron for running batch programs but I don't know to write a query for backing up my `userdatas` collection every month.

How can I do this in Node.js, express.js and mongodb?

Comment: if you want to backup, why still store in same database? why not just store in a file? anyway you plan to allow user to download it through expressjs rest api right?

Comment: file or  database but i need to store everyone month data and i need to delete that one month data in 'userdatas' collection

Answer (score 2):

**mongodb-snapshot**

https://github.com/lihaibh/mongodb-snapshot/tree/83b12d377a1ec387f0bcf121b294cdd45504ac76

*install*

```
npm i mongodb-snapshot
```

*add this function*

```
async function mongoSnap(path, restore = false) {
    const mongo_connector = new BKP.MongoDBDuplexConnector({
        connection: { uri: mongoCString, dbname: dbName }
    });
    const localfile_connector = new BKP.LocalFileSystemDuplexConnector({
        connection: { path: path }
    });
    const transferer = restore ? 
        new BKP.MongoTransferer({ source: localfile_connector, targets: [mongo_connector] }) : 
        new BKP.MongoTransferer({ source: mongo_connector, targets: [localfile_connector] }) ;
    for await (const { total, write } of transferer) { }
}
```

*use like*

```
await mongoSnap('./backups/collections.tar'); // backup

await mongoSnap('./backups/collections.tar', true); // restore
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run find query on **userdatas** table and than inside it use insert query to insert data in **backupuserdatas** table.

I know it's not a good solution but for small data you can use it.

For running multiple queries inside you need to use [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md) for synchronize behavior of node. Hope this will help you.

You can do it by using following code in your node-cron section like this:

```
mongoose.users.find({}, function(err, result){
    var data = {};
    var curr_date = new Date();
    data["user_data"] = result;
    data["created"] = curr_date;
    var savebackup = new mongoose.backup_user(data);
    savebackup.save(function(err,res){
        // save done
        mongoose.users.remove({}, function(err, result){});
    });
});
```

Here I created one backup table named "backup_user" and the user table is "users".

This will save your all users data to backup_user table each time you run your node-cron api.

Comment: can you pls help me out for this. m not able to understand

Comment: please check the answer again I updated it with code.

Comment: after taking backup i need to delete 'users' collection data's how can i do that in your query .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867811/how-to-do-user-already-there-update-if-not-there-create-in-particular-collecti

Answer (score 1):

You can use below modules 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-backup
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-restore

You can also take the backup and restore the specific collections using options